# Diffs in git pull request not updated when code in base branch changes

Tags: git, github, branch, rebase, pull-request

Here's the flow of what's happening to me right now in git:

1. Create branch B off branch A.
2. Do work in branch B.
3. Create a pull request to merge branch B into branch A.
4. While waiting for feedback, create branch C off branch B so I can continue working without messing up the PR.
5. Continue working in branch C.
6. Create a PR to merge branch C into branch A (this now contains diffs from both sets of work).
7. The first PR is approved & branch B is squashed and merged into branch A.
8. **Rebase branch C off branch A with the expectation that half the diffs in the second PR will disappear.**
9. Be disappointed.

The second pull request still shows both sets of work as being new when compared with the base branch, even though the base branch already has half that work now.  I even tried creating a brand new PR and got the same results.

Is this expected and correct behavior, or have I run into a weird git abnormality?

Comment: You did push after the last rebase, right?

Comment: @eftshift0 Yes.  We do a "git push --force-with-lease" after each rebase.